# MIPS program to use floating point numbers?

Tags: floating-point, mips

I have a program which takes in 10 ints and then lists out all the ints greater or equal to the last integer entered. I have to change it so that it accepts floating point numbers instead of integers. How might I go about this?

```
        .data
        .align 0

array:
        .space 40
messageOne:
        .asciiz "Please enter 10 integers. IF you wish to stop before 10 numbers, enter '-1'."
messageTwo:
        .asciiz "Enter an integer:\n "
messageThree:
        .asciiz "Integers greater or equal to the last integer entered (In the order they were entered). \nThis list also includes the last number entered (bottom of list).\n"
return:
        .asciiz "\n"

        .text
        .globl main
main:
        # message one
        la          $a0, messageOne                     # Load string address of messageOne
    li          $v0, 4                                  # syscall code - print string
    syscall
    addi        $s0, $zero, -1                      # $s0 = -1
    addi        $s4, $zero, 10                      # $s4 = 10
    la          $s1, array                              # Load array into $s1
    j           intake                                  # go to intake loop
    syscall

intake:
    beq         $s3, $s4, last                      # Check if input counter is a 10 stored in $s4, if so jump to "final" subroutine

    # Bring in integers
    la          $a0, messageTwo                     # Load address of messageTwo
    li          $v0, 4                                  # syscall code - print string
    syscall

    # Integer input into temp register
    # Read int from user
    li          $v0, 5                              # syscakk code - read integer
    syscall

    move        $t0, $v0                            # move to temp at $t0
    beq         $t0, $s0, last                  # if value is -1, jump to end
    sw          $t0, ($s1)                          # store in array
    move        $s2, $t0                            # store as last entered in $s2

    addi        $s1, $s1, 4                         # offset address
    addi        $s3, $s3, 1                         # increment counter

    j       intake                                      # Loop intake

last:
        # Print new line
    la          $a0, return                         # new line
    li          $v0, 4                                  # syscall code - print string
    syscall

    la          $a0, messageThree                       # final message
    li          $v0, 4                                  # syscall code - print 
    syscall

    # Reset a registers
    la          $s1, array                              # load array into $s1

loop:

    beq         $s3, $zero, quit                    # exit if no more intake

    lw      $t0, ($s1)

    # use set less than to determine integers greater than last integer entered
    slt         $t1, $t0, $s2                           # Use slt to determine ints greater than last
    beq         $t1, $zero, print                   # print if $t1 = $zero

    addi        $s1, $s1, 4                         # offset address
    addi        $s3, $s3, -1                        # educe from counter by 1

    j       loop                                    # Loop loop

print:
    # Print the value in the current offset
    lw          $a0, ($s1)                              # load current value from array
    li          $v0, 1                                  # syscall code - print 
    syscall

    addi        $s1, $s1, 4                         # offset address
    addi        $s3, $s3, -1                        # increment by -1

    # Print new line
    la          $a0, return                         # new line
    li          $v0, 4                                  # syscall code - print 
    syscall

    j       loop                                    # go back to the beginning of loop

quit:                                   
li              $v0, 10                         # service code for exit
    syscall
```

Comment: _"How might I go about this?"_ You would look up [the appropriate system calls](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html) to use for reading and writing floating point numbers, and then you'd look up the appropriate instructions to use for processing those numbers in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II_. That's about as specific as one can be for such a vague question. If you have trouble understanding a certain instruction or system call you should edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

In general:

1. Instead of using the integer registers, use the floating point registers (`$f0` to `$f31`)
2. Use [floating point instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set#Floating_point) instead of regular instructions for math on floating point.
3. Use floating point system calls.

The rest should not be hard to figure out.

Comment: I tried doing that, but whenever I try and use `add.s` followed by the float registers, it keeps saying "incorrect type"